# Initializing scope variables in controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am completely new to AngularJS and followed a course and started "learning" this framework. I watched the 2 screencasts at the top of this page:

https://github.com/curran/screencasts/tree/gh-pages/introToAngular

After watching both screencasts and looking into some of the examples I tried to create my own simple Angular application where I tried to work with some controllers. Now I have the following code:

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="WIMT">
<head>
    <title>trying out angularJS</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="controllerA as a">
    {{a.varA}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="controllerB as b">
    {{b.varB}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="controllerC as c">
    {{c.varC}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('WIMT',[]);


app.controller('controllerA',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.varA = "A";
});

app.controller('controllerB',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.varB = "B";
}
]);

app.controller('controllerC',function($scope, $http) {
    var reg = this;

    reg.varC = "C";
});

})();
```

After I tried to bind varA to the scope in controller A I found out that it didn't work and I looked for a solution on the internet. I have found a few different ways (B & C) that should (could?) work. Only option C works and shows C when I run the html. Both A & B show nothing.

Why do option A and B not work in this example?

Comment: Btw, you don't have to encase your angular app in a self-executing anonymous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `controllerAs` syntax, that's why the third one is working and first two are not.

```
<div ng-controller="controllerA as a">
    {{a.varA}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="controllerB as b">
    {{b.varB}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="controllerC as c">
    {{c.varC}}
</div>
```

If you want the `a.varA` and `b.varB` to print, you have to change to below:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controllerA as a">
    {{varA}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="controllerB as b">
        {{varB}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="controllerC as c">
        {{c.varC}}
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t0hhp5wz/

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, your solution does work. But this leaves me with a question: Why would I use controllerA as a if I don't directly use a.varA but varA?

Comment: You should not use, i just gave you an example on how to print... its best to use controllerAs syntax over using $scope.

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty the same thing :

```
app.controller('controllerA',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.varA = "A";
});
```

this syntax will work if you use minification, the previous not.

```
app.controller('controllerB',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.varB = "B";
}
]);
```

use this syntax in the view :

```
 <div ng-controller="controllerA">
  {{varA}}
</div>
```

Comment: It is generally considered best practice to use the controllerAs syntax. Not this one.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `controller as` alias, option A & B are placed inside controller scopes which are childScopes of `$scope`.

if you `console.log` the `$scope` you will see option A & B created inside controller scope and not in `$scope` which is parent scope for those controllers.

Comment: `$scope` IS the controller's scope. `controller as` adds the **controller as** property to the scope.

Comment: controller's scope...? I thought scope specific to the controller will be created when we use the directive approach. please clarify me on this.

Comment: `ng-controller` creates a scope that can be accessed with `$scope` in the controller. `controller as vm` adds the controller instance as property `vm` to the scope. Within the controller `this` would be equal to `$scope.vm`. So `this.a` would be equal to `$scope.vm.a`, and `{{vm.a}}` in the template. But there is only one scope, not two, as your answer suggests.

Comment: thanks for clarification. yeah I meant the controllers as chile scopes which is not the case at all :D